# How to properly compare a string to another string

Tags: java, string-comparison

I have a problem with below `if` condition.

```
if(!(type=="image/jpeg" || type=="image/png" || type=="image/gif")){
    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Only jpeg, png or gif", ""));
}
```

When `type` is `image/jpeg`, it still throws `ValidatorException`. When I hardcode `type` directly to `image/jpeg`, it works. So I hope that you help me, because I really don't know where is problem.

Comment: Problem in if statement, you need to debug with sop and find out in String type = file.getContentType(); what is value of type then need to check same value in if statement with equals() method

Comment: Thanks, it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and found exception that why you are not getting correct output, you need to change

```
if(!(type.equals("image/jpeg") || type.equals("image/png") || type.equals("image/gif")){
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Only jpeg, png or gif", ""));
        }
```

**NOTE**: First you need to debug with `System.out.println("Type value: "+type);` that which output format is coming then need to put same format to check validation in if statement like *type.equals("jpeg") or type.equals("image/jpeg").*

It is working for me, I hope it will work for you also.